# upgradepkg uses wrong version of python for package installs

Tags: python, linux, pygame, slackware

I'm using slackware that has python 2.6 by default.  I've installed python 2.7 and successfully insatlled numpy and scipy and matplotlib into python 2.7 using slackbuilds and pip.

However, when I try to install pygame using:

```
upgradepkg --install-new pygame-1.9.1-x86_64-1sl.txz
```

it installs to python 2.6 (the txz came from pkgs.org)

Is there a way to specify in `upgradepkg` which python version I want to us? I suppose the sure way is to unpack the pygame file, get into it and change some values, then repack it, then run the upgrade command again... but I don't really know what I'm doing so I wanted to see if there's a simpler way before I embark on that journey.

UPDATE: I'm having the same problem with PyGTK, so I'm starting to think it's something in the settings of upgradepkg... haven't been able to word the question right on Google to come up with a solution

Comment: Which version of Slackware? I suggest you use the build scripts from http://slackbuilds.org/.

Comment: 13.37 the only one available for pygame was 13.1.  Though... I did accidentally install numpy, blas, lapack, and scipy form the 14.0 version... but they seemed to work so far.

Comment: thought it doesn't answer this particular question, I found out the problem.  Pip was pointing to the macosx version of pygame, so I just called pip with an explicit http address pointing to a linux version and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

That just means that the package was built for Python 2.6. Paths in packages are hardcoded, there is no way to change them. You have to rebuild the package from sources on your system, or find one that was made on a system with 2.7 installed.

Anyway, if all you need is Python stuff, have a look at pip: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html